# How can I make an external API call by providing pem, key file and CRT file

Tags: php, ssl, curl, postman

How to perform cert-based auth with a PHP.
I have an external APi which requires below files.

- PEM file : Secure_Server_CA.crt
- CRT file : mywebiste.crt
- KEY file : private_key.key

I have tested that api in post man by providing these files and got response.. but when i do same in PHP script im getting error

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, __DIR__ . '/ssl/mywebsite.crt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, __DIR__ . '/ssl/private_key.key');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ .'/ssl/Secure_Server_CA.crt');
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

> Curl error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate

When I add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

> Curl error: OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/1.1.1w: error:14094418:SSL
> routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca, errno 0

Im not able to get repsonse in php script. but these same certifcates are working perfect in post man and providing response.

I want to get the repsonse via PHP script

Comment: What do you get when you use postman's option to _create_ PHP cURL code for the request for you?

Comment: Make sure you have updated your system cacert

Comment: I have placed all three files of SSL related in my ftp.. and mentioned path in my php code.. but not able to get response..